# ckeditor auto show svg object

Tags: javascript, svg, ckeditor

I need to allow auto show svg element, pasted in editor's area.
How can I do this without adding any buttons to toolbar?

`<object data="/static/media/charts/fe0e11f14f56a456.svg" width="300" height="100" 
type="image/svg+xml"
codebase="/images/" />`

This code after adding to area will automatically show as object, not plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found decision:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    on: {
        paste: function(evt) {
            var editor = evt.editor;
            console.log(evt);
            if (evt.data.dataValue.match(/object/)) {
                evt.data.dataValue = evt.data.dataValue.replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&gt;', '>');
                var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(evt.data.dataValue);
                editor.insertElement(element);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the share! You can accept your answer too.